# Attaching a fabric/ribbon border to a bamboo shade

Tags: upholstery

I would like to attach a ribbon or fabric border to my bamboo shade at the bottom of the valence piece. Since the shade material isn’t fabric, I’m thinking the best method would be to use a hot glue gun. Any other suggestions other than a glue gun method? Thanks!

I tried uploading a picture but I’m not sure if it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I think hot glue would be the easiest and would do a fine job of holding the fabric in place.

The drawback is that hot glue can change the appearance of the fabric. I recommend using a swatch of fabric as a test piece to ensure that any change caused by application of hot glue is acceptable to you...

Comment: I would also use hot glue, my wife makes decorations for our horse stalls with hot glue and it holds up quite well with both ribbon and lace, but check it as jimmy suggests some ribbon she used had plastic in it and the hot glue melted the plastic.+